# Is it possible to remember the state of a composable function?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to remember the state of a variable of type `@Composable ()->Unit`, I get no compiler errors but the app crashes on launch.

Why does this happen and what is the best way to fix it?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
@Composable
fun App(isHappy: Boolean) {
    var page: @Composable ()->Unit by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf({}) }

    val happy = @Composable {
        Text("I'm happy")
    }

    val sad = @Composable {
        Text("I'm sad")
        Text("and angry!")
    }

    page = if(isHappy) happy else sad

    page()
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            App(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [moveableContentOf](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/runtime/runtime/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/runtime/samples/MovableContentSamples.kt;l=33?q=movableContentOf).

Comment: @adneal This feature seems to be in alpha. Isn't there a way to do it with stable features? Besides, I couldn't figure out how to install the alpha version

Answer (score 4):

A composable function can be "remembered" but it is not "savable" as it is not serializable because it can easily capture state that is not serializable. Trying to use it in a `rememberSavable` will cause a runtime exception.

Consider, instead, remembering the value used to calculate the composable function, not the resulting function. For example,

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    var isHappy by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }

    val happy = @Composable {
        Text("I'm happy")
    }

    val sad = @Composable {
        Text("I'm sad")
        Text("and angry!")
    }

    val page = if (isHappy) happy else sad

    Column {
      page()
      Button({ isHappy = !isHappy }) {
        Text("Toggle happiness")
      }
    }
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            App()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's a real bummer that it's not possible to save a function as it would have been the most elegant solution to my problem I think. I did try to use a ["rust enum"](https://blog.shadura.me/2019/09/25/kotlin-enums/) instead (normal enums aren't enough for my needs as since I need some values to have parameters) but that also caused a crush