# Jetpack Compose TopAppBar with dynamic actions

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation
)
```

**actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {}**

**Usage Scenario:**
Using Compose Navigation to switch to different "screens", so the TopAppBar actions will be changed accordingly.  Eg. Share buttons for content screen,  Filter button for listing screen

Tried passing as a state to the TopAppBar's actions parameter, but having trouble to save the lambda block for the `remember` function.

```
val (actions, setActions) = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf( appBarActions ) }
```

Want to change the app bar actions content dynamically.  Any way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71285467/is-it-possible-to-remember-the-state-of-a-composable-function

Answer (score 25):

This the approach I used but I'm pretty new on compose, so I cannot be sure it is the correct approach.

Let's assume I have 2 screens: ScreenA and ScreenB
They are handled by MainActivity screen.
This is our MainActivity:

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CoolDrinksTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    var appBarState by remember {
                        mutableStateOf(AppBarState())
                    }

                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            SmallTopAppBar(
                                title = {
                                    Text(text = appBarState.title)
                                },
                                actions = {
                                    appBarState.actions?.invoke(this)
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    ) { values ->
                        NavHost(
                            navController = navController,
                            startDestination = "screen_a",
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                                values
                            )
                        ) {
                            composable("screen_a") {
                                ScreenA(
                                    onComposing = {
                                        appBarState = it
                                    },
                                    navController = navController
                                )
                            }
                            composable("screen_b") {
                                ScreenB(
                                    onComposing = {
                                        appBarState = it
                                    },
                                    navController = navController
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using a mutable state of a class which represents the state of our MainActivity (where the TopAppBar is declared and composed), in this example there is the title and the actions of our TopAppBar.

This mutable state is set with a callback function called inside the composition of each screen.

Here you can see the ScreenA

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA(
    onComposing: (AppBarState) -> Unit,
    navController: NavController
) {

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        onComposing(
            AppBarState(
                title = "My Screen A",
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Favorite,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Filter,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Screen A"
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            navController.navigate("screen_b")
        }) {
            Text(text = "Navigate to Screen B")
        }
    }
}
```

And the ScreenB

```
@Composable
fun ScreenB(
    onComposing: (AppBarState) -> Unit,
    navController: NavController
) {

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        onComposing(
            AppBarState(
                title = "My Screen B",
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Home,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                    IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Screen B"
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            navController.popBackStack()
        }) {
            Text(text = "Navigate back to Screen A")
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the data class of our state:

```
data class AppBarState(
    val title: String = "",
    val actions: (@Composable RowScope.() -> Unit)? = null
)
```

In this way you have a dynamic appbar declared in the main activity but each screen is responsable to handle the content of the appbar.

Comment: Works well. Need to use "TopAppBar" instead of "SmallTopAppBar", which is now deprecated.

Comment: Yes you right. Now Small Topappbar is deprecated

Comment: Nice solution, will try it

Comment: This solution worked also for me for a few month. Now I tried to use fastlane to take screenshots for GooglePlay but on the screenshots, the TopAppBar is empty. No title, no actions. The `LaunchedEffect` in "ScreenB" is called, tested it with logs. Does anyone have an Idea why no titles and actions are shown? I even tried to add a wait before taking the screenshot, but same result. Seeing the length of my comment... maybe I should start my own question.

Comment: Nevermind. You need something like `composeTestRule.waitUntilAtLeastOneExists(hasText("Title Text"), 1000)` before `Screengrab.screenshot("image")` because to title shows only after a recomposition.

Answer (score 4):

If your navigation is using compose-navigation, you can try this way.

1. Define compose Components

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowScope
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveableStateHolder
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.LocalViewModelStoreOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry
import androidx.navigation.compose.LocalOwnersProvider

@Composable
fun ProvideAppBarAction(actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit) {
    if (LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current == null || LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current !is NavBackStackEntry)
        return
    val actionViewModel = viewModel(initializer = { TopAppBarViewModel() })
    SideEffect {
        actionViewModel.actionState = actions
    }
}

@Composable
fun ProvideAppBarTitle(title: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    if (LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current == null || LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current !is NavBackStackEntry)
        return
    val actionViewModel = viewModel(initializer = { TopAppBarViewModel() })
    SideEffect {
        actionViewModel.titleState = title
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.AppBarAction(navBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry?) {
    val stateHolder = rememberSaveableStateHolder()
    navBackStackEntry?.LocalOwnersProvider(stateHolder) {
        val actionViewModel = viewModel(initializer = { TopAppBarViewModel() })
        actionViewModel.actionState?.let { it() }
    }
}


@Composable
fun AppBarTitle(navBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry?) {
    val stateHolder = rememberSaveableStateHolder()
    navBackStackEntry?.LocalOwnersProvider(stateHolder) {
        val actionViewModel = viewModel(initializer = { TopAppBarViewModel() })
        actionViewModel.titleState?.let { it() }
    }
}


private class TopAppBarViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var titleState by mutableStateOf(null as (@Composable () -> Unit)?, referentialEqualityPolicy())
    var actionState by mutableStateOf(null as (@Composable RowScope.() -> Unit)?, referentialEqualityPolicy())

}
```

2. consume the composable components from appbar using viewModel

```
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(navController:NavController) {
    val currentContentBackStackEntry by produceState(
        initialValue = null as NavBackStackEntry?,
        producer = {
            navController.currentBackStackEntryFlow
                .filterNot { it.destination is FloatingWindow }
                .collect{ value = it }
        }
    )
    TopAppBar(
        navigationIcon = {
            val backPressDispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current
            IconButton(
                onClick = { backPressDispatcher?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed() },
                content = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBackIos,
                        contentDescription = "arrowBackIos"
                    )
                }
            )
        },
        title = {
            AppBarTitle(currentContentBackStackEntry)
        },
        actions = {
            AppBarAction(currentContentBackStackEntry)
        }
    )
}
```

3. use the provider function inside the composable destination

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.buildGraph() {
    composable(route = "start1") {
        ProvideAppBarTitle { Text("1") }
        ProvideAppBarAction {
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "action1")
            }
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "action2")
            }
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "action3")
            }
        }
    }
    composable(route = "start2") {
        ProvideAppBarTitle{ Text("2") }
        ProvideAppBarAction{
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "action1")
            }
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "action2")
            }
            Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Text(text = "action3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Detail explanation

- Composable lamba is stored by the viewModel that is controlled by NavBackStackEntry
- If we know the NavController, we can easily access the NavBackStackEntry
- Actions and title can have their own state restored thx to NavBackStackEntry, Actions and Title composable are restored at the time the composesable destination restored.

side notes: You can wrap the AppBarTitle and AppBarAction with animation

```
@Composable
fun MyTopAppBar(navController:NavController) {
    val currentContentBackStackEntry by produceState(
        initialValue = null as NavBackStackEntry?,
        producer = {
            navController.currentBackStackEntryFlow
                .filterNot { it.destination is FloatingWindow }
                .collect{ value = it }
        }
    )
    TopAppBar(
        navigationIcon = {
            val backPressDispatcher = LocalOnBackPressedDispatcherOwner.current
            IconButton(
                onClick = { backPressDispatcher?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.onBackPressed() },
                content = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBackIos,
                        contentDescription = "arrowBackIos"
                    )
                }
            )
        },
        title = {
            Crossfade(targetState = currentContentBackStackEntry, label = "AppBarTitle") {
                if (it != null) {
                    AppBarTitle(it)
                }
            }
        },
        actions = {
            Crossfade(targetState = currentContentBackStackEntry, label = "AppBarActions") {
                if (it != null) {
                    Row{
                        AppBarAction(currentContentBackStackEntry)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this response! I have implemented this nice approach and it works perfectly. But, if I try to extend it to dynamically change the topbar colors it doesn't work. I have created the functions: `ProvideAppBarColors` and `AppBarColors`, adding a `colorsState` property to the viewModel. But I get an error in `MyTopAppBar`, when I try: `TopAppBar( colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors({AppBarColors(currentContentBackStackEntry)},`. The error message is: *`Cannot find a parameter with this name: containerColor`*. Why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: @A.Cedano well cause you can not create TopAppBarColors like that.
see https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/TopAppBarDefaults#topAppBarColors(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)

Answer (score 0):

### you can try this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AppTopBar(navController: NavController, title:String, actions:@Composable ()->Unit ){
    CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(title)
        },
        actions={
            actions()
        }
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TopAppBarPreview(){
    VdcallTheme {
        AppTopBar(rememberNavController(),"Home",
            {x()}
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun x(){
    IconButton(
        onClick = {  }
    ){
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
            contentDescription = "Localized description"
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to add navigation dependency on you jetpack compose projects.

You can read the doc from this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

```
def nav_version = "2.4.1"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
```

Then define your screen in sealed class:

```
sealed class Screen(var icon: ImageVector, var route: String) {
    object ContentScreen: Screen(Icons.Default.Home, "home")
    object ListingScreen: Screen(Icons.Default.List, "list")
}
```

and this is the navigation function look like

```
@Composable
fun Navigation(paddingValues: PaddingValues, navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = Screen.ContentScreen.route, modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
        composable(Screen.ContentScreen.route) {
            //your screen content
        }
        composable(Screen.ListingScreen.route) {
            //your listing screen here
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in your mainactivity class

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestAppTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
                Scaffold(
                    topBar = {
                        TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "main screen") }, actions = {
                            if (currentRoute == Screen.ContentScreen.route) {
                                //your share button action here
                            } else if (currentRoute == Screen.ListingScreen.route) {
                                //your filter button here
                            } else {
                                //other action
                            }
                        })
                    }
                ) {
                    Navigation(paddingValues = it, navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm so sorry if the explanation to sort, because the limitation of my English

Comment: This could possibly work, but I am looking for a way to decentralise the action button logic into each respective screen class.   Imagine navigation bar title scenario, try to avoid defining all screen titles at the root level screen.