# Android Compose - How to implement different TopAppBar design according to specific screens (with Navigation Drawer)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, appbar

Here is my question, I would like different **TopAppBar** design according to the screen selected in the **Drawer**.

- **Screen 1** -> a simple **TopAppBar** with **Title** and **NavigationIcon**
- **Screen 2** -> a **TopAppBar** with **Tabs** bellow the title and a **Pager**
- **Screen 3** -> same as Screen1 but with 2 action buttons

This is my MainScreen Composable, with the **TopAppBar**, the **Navigation** and the **Drawer** setup:

```
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    @Composable
    fun MainScreen() {
        val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed))
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        val baseTitle = ""
        val (title, setTitle) = remember { mutableStateOf(baseTitle) }
        val (canPop, setCanPop) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        DisposableEffect(navController) {
            val listener = NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
                setCanPop(controller.previousBackStackEntry != null)
            }
            navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
            onDispose {
                navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(listener)
            }
        }

        Scaffold(
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = { Text(text = title) },
                    backgroundColor = Color.Blue,
                    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                    navigationIcon = {
                        if (canPop) {
                            IconButton(
                                onClick = {
                                    navController.popBackStack()
                                }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.ArrowBack,
                                    contentDescription = "Back arrow"
                                )
                            }
                        } else {
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                scope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }
                            }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Menu,
                                    contentDescription = "Menu button"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            },
            drawerBackgroundColor = Color.White,
            drawerGesturesEnabled = scaffoldState.drawerState.isOpen,
            drawerContent = {
                Drawer(
                    scope = scope,
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
        ) {
            Navigation(
                navController = navController,
                setTitle = setTitle
            )
        }
    }
```

Here is how I handle navigation between the different screens :

```
    @Composable
        fun Navigation(
            navController: NavHostController,
            setTitle: (String) -> Unit,
        ) {
            NavHost(navController, startDestination = "home") {
                composable(route = "home") {
                    HomeScreen(
                        homeState = homeViewModel.state,
                        setTitle = setTitle
                    )
                }
                composable(route = MenuItem.Screen1.route) {
                    Screen1(setTitle = setTitle)
                }
                composable(route = MenuItem.Screen2.route) {
                    Screen2(setTitle = setTitle)
                }
                composable(route = MenuItem.Screen3.route) {
                   Screen3(setTitle = setTitle)
                }
            }
        }
```

The **MenuItem** is just a sealed class with a route, a title and an icon for the drawer.

Just to quickly show you the navigate action in the **Drawer** :

```kotlin
    DrawerBody(
        items = menuItems,
        modifier = Modifier,
        onItemClick = { item ->
            navController.navigate(item.route) {
                navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                    popUpTo(route) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                }
                launchSingleTop = true
                restoreState = true
            }
            scope.launch {
                scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
            }
        }
    )
```

How to handle the creation of specific **Scaffold** for each screen? Should I create it directly in the associated screens? How the **Navigation** will be handled if I do so? If I move out the Scaffold from my MainActivity to each specific Screen, I will loose the navigation logic with the Navigation Drawer.

For now, I just created the same TopAppBar in all my screens.

Comment: I think you can have an idea from my previous answer for dynamic TopAppbar, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417326/jetpack-compose-topappbar-with-dynamic-actions/75846287#75846287)